# Is it bad practice to let content overflow under controlled conditions?

Tags: html, css, markup

As the title suggests, I'm working front-end trying to make a website where I noticed that letting content overflow in some situations is beneficial to the user experience. I'm just not sure if there's any programmatic issues with letting the content of a div live outside of its parent, and it is working out pretty well for me. The content in never overlapping, just occasionally exceeding the parent div's width.

Is there anything that could go wrong? Any accessibility issues?

Comment: Well, if you have a black background, a white div with black text in it, and let that overflow, it will be pretty hard to read the overflowing text. But your question is practically impossible to answer, because almost everything could go wrong, but again under the right circumstances, nothing could go wrong at all.

Comment: Without a screenshot or demo code, I have no idea how your overflow would look, so how can we tell you whether anything could go wrong?

Comment: @billy, Maybe you knew of some general accessibility rule or common browser compatibility issue.

Comment: A lot of things contribute to accessibility. For instance, small buttons on mobile view is poor accessibility but it's fine on desktop / laptop. Design is always about making the right compromise, so the only 'general rule' is to stick to the standards if you're not sure whether it works and only do it your way if you are confident that it's better than the conventional way. A well-coded page shouldn't have overflowed content unless it's intentional (such as FB hiding the scrollbar, for example).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bad approach. Content should not overflow. Also, div's should be flexible in height and fixed in width, or with a percentage width.

You could set `overflow-x: auto;` to get a scroll bar.

Accessibility issues might occur on mobile devices.

Comment: I'm making a 12 column grid-system which is pixel based. When 1 column is significantly taller than the one next to it, the content below the neighboring  column is free to span two column widths. I can't do that without letting the content flow outside of its actual column width.

Comment: If it spans two column widths, then it's fine. It means you now have 11 columns on a row, and one of them is double. If it spans two columns, you're okay, if it spans, say, 23px, then it's not okay.